# Does Waydroid support debian v10 (buster)?

Tags: debian

How to install waydroid in debian-v10?

Comment: What research have *you* done on the topic?

Comment: See https://www.debian.org/releases/  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history (both URLs are easily found by searching for "debian versions" or "debian version names" or similar - they're the top 2 results on duckduckgo)

Comment: the answer you got for your previous question had a link for installing waydroid on "Ubuntu, Debian and Derivates" (including deepin).  i.e. it's the same answer for an almost identical question.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian/Ubuntu [Install Instructions](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-on-desktops) in [Waydroid documentation](https://docs.waydro.id/) states:

> If the script fails to detect your distribution, you can provide a
> valid option by appending -s . Currently supported values are:
> focal, jammy, kinetic, lunar, bookworm, bullseye, sid

If you want to run it on an older version, you will need to build from [source](https://github.com/waydroid).